Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding', The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class and others
I’m totally new to Flutter and got handed this project. I don’t know who made it. My friend’s cousin commissioned it from someone, but it looks like the project has been abandoned. My friend wants to see if we can get it up and running. Any tips for getting this Flutter project running?
I’m hitting multiple errors:
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.10.4/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:85:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1643:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Scaffold({
        ^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:432:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:440:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:451:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:463:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:475:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:487:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:499:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:510:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:521:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:532:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:544:15: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.
 - 'BasicMessageChannel' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart' ('../../../Documents/Apps/Flutter/2.5.0/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
      channel.setMockMessageHandler((dynamic message) async {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

Some info
Flutter version 2.5.0
Dart version 2.14.0

As you can see in this flutter archive, the latest flutter stable version is 3.24.4.
Your flutter and dart version is outdated. So what you need to do is upgrade your flutter sdk and the packages.
Upgrade flutter sdk from command line / terminal:
flutter upgrade

Upgrade your packages:
flutter pub upgrade

Then clean your project:
flutter clean

After clean, before you run your project get the package first by:
flutter pub get

and last run your project
flutter run


Due to the flutter version gap so far, I expect there will be some errors appearing in your code.

